# Perform method when an attribute is added to a class in Python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, methods, setattr

I would like to instantiate a class, say, `Fighter` with and without the attribute `weapon_size`.  But when the attribute `weapon_size` is set (either at instantiation or later) I want to run some method which adds another attribute `damage` (and perhaps does some other calculations).  I'm trying to do this by overloading the **setattr** function as below.

My question: is this the correct [and sensible] way to do this?

```
class Fighter(object):
    def __init__(self, prenom, weapon_size = None):
        self._prenom = prenom
        self._weapon_size = weapon_size
        if not weapon_size is None:
            self.AddWeapon(weapon_size)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            if name == "weapon_size":
                print "Adding weapon"
                self.AddWeapon(value)
                self.__dict__['_' + name] = value
            else:
                self.__dict__[name] = value

    def AddWeapon(self, x):
        self._damage = x/2.

    @property
    def weapon_size(self):
        "Weapon size"
        return self._weapon_size
    @property
    def prenom(self):
        "First name"
        return self._prenom

U = Fighter('Greg')
U.weapon_size = 9
print U.weapon_size, U._damage
>> 9 4.5
W = Fighter('Jeff', weapon_size = 11)
print W.weapon_size, W._damage
>> 11 5.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom setter for the specific property.

```
@weapon_size.setter
def weapon_size(self, value):
    # custom code here
    self._weapon_size = value
```

EDIT: But really, at the end of the day, I think it's much cleaner for you to simply do:

```
class Fighter(object):
    def __init__(self, prenom, weapon_size=None):
        ...
        self.weapon_size = weapon_size
        ...

    @property
    def damage(self):
        if self.weapon_size:
            return self.weapon_size / 2
        return None
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  

Can I ask, what would be the downside to using __setattr__?  That I handle cases that I shouldn't handle?

Comment: Because properties were basically created for the exact problem you are trying to solve. Overriding any `__x__` method should always be avoided if possible. With `__setattr__` your modifying a method that gets called for all attributes, when all you care about is `weapon_size`. This way is more precise.